# Label 'Yii' already defined

Tags: php, yii

I am starting to learn Yii framework. In the tutorial video i copied the code where were using setFlash for error messages on a form. I have inspected the code a lot of times and im pretty sure its identical to the video however i keep getting an error message that is referring to this line:

```
Yii:app()->user->setFlash('failure', "There was a problem saving the data!");
```

The error says:

```
Fatal error: Label 'Yii' already defined in C:\wamp\www\photogallery\protected\controllers\AlbumController.php on line 77

public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Album;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Album']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Album'];
        if($model->save()){
            Yii:app()->user->setFlash('saved', "Data saved!");
            $this->redirect(array('update','id'=>$model->id));
        } else{
            Yii:app()->user->setFlash('failure', "There was a problem saving the data!");
        }

    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Maybe its a typo im missing but its exactly the same as the video tutorial and it seems to work for him and i took a look at some other similar code online and it seemed to use 2 instances of Yii:app() in an if/else statement. The error message didnt return any similar issues on google so im guessing its something simple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a double colon, not single, when using the static method.

`Yii::app()` not `Yii:app()`

Comment: You have no idea how many times i went over that code and didnt see that, cheers